# dbContext is Disposed in a Time Hosted Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I'm trying to get my TimeHostedService with a DBContext to work but I always get the error: `Cannot access a disposed context instance`. So here is my Code:

First of all, I have my `DoWork` Method inside my Time Hosted Service. Because the class that I call (`IEasyConficService`) is scoped and the TimeHosted Service is singleton, I have to implement it with the scope.ServiceProvider. I think, this is so far fine.

```cs
private void DoWork(object? state)
{
    using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var easyConfigService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEasyConfigService>();
    easyConfigService.ExecuteUnfinishedEasyConfigs();
}
```

Now my function `ExecuteUnfinishedEasyConfigs` is collecting all the unfinished Gateways that I have from the Database. And then give it to the Method 'TryExecuteEasyConfig'.

```cs
public async Task ExecuteUnfinishedEasyConfigs()
{
    var gateways = _context.Gateways.Include(g => g.Machine)
        .Where(g => g.EasyConfigStatus == EasyConfigStatus.OnGoing)
        .Include(g => g.Machine)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.MachineType)
        .ToList();
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(gateways, async (gateway, _) => await TryExecuteEasyConfig(gateway));
}
```

This works so far, because the `_context` is set in the constructor of the class with DI.

```cs
public class EasyConfigService : IEasyConfigService {
    private readonly SuncarContext _context;
    
    public EasyConfigService(SuncarContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

But inside the `TryExecuteEasyConfig` method, which is also in the class `EasyConfigService`, I get the disposed Error from above, if I try call `_context.SaveChangesAsync()`

```cs
private async Task TryExecuteEasyConfig(Gateway gateway)
{
    // Do some Stuff
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I do not know, why I can first take some Information out of the DBContext and afterwards the `SaveChangesAsync()` is failing. Why is the _context now disposed?

First I thought, it is because I do a Parallel.FoarEachAsync but it also happend, if I do a normal foreach. Is there any way to use a `DBContext` safely inside a `TimeHostedService`?

**Edit 15.06.2023 11:12**

The normal foreach is looking like:

```cs
foreach (var gateway in gateways)
{
    await TryExecuteEasyConfig(gateway);
}
```

**Edit 15.06.2023 11:16**

The SuncarContext is added as following:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<SuncarContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresConnection"),
        sqlOption =>
        {
            sqlOption.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                5,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                null);
        }
    ));
```

**Edit 15.06.2023 11.21**

The Time Hosted Service is Using the StartAsync Method, where I use a Timer, that is calling a DoWork Method.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Backend.BusinessLayer.Services.Interfaces;

public class EasyConfigExecutor : IHostedService, IDisposable {
    private readonly ILogger<EasyConfigExecutor> _logger;
    private Timer? _timer;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public EasyConfigExecutor(ILogger<EasyConfigExecutor> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object? state)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var easyConfigService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IEasyConfigService>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
        easyConfigService.ExecuteUnfinishedEasyConfigs();
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Edit 15.06.2023 14.22 - Conclusion**

The Answer of Dai definitely works. Thanks for your support.

After looking through the Internet, I found also a good article from Microsoft, how to use timed asynchronous background task in c#. That's the way I'm using it now. Probably this will help some other people: [Micosoft Timed asynchronous background Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#asynchronous-timed-background-task)

Comment: could you show also your approach with foreach loop?

Comment: Why are you mixing non-async and async code together?

Comment: Please show the full definition of `class EasyConfigService` including fields - it sounds like `_context` is a `static` field when it shouldn't.

Comment: Also, where-and-how are you registering `IEasyConfigService`? Are you validating your lifetimes, scopes and registrations?

Comment: The IEasyConfigService I register to the services as Transient:

`services.AddTransient<IEasyConfigService, EasyConfigService>();`

Comment: How are you registering `SuncarContext` ?

Comment: @AdalyatNazirov I posted above in my comment, how i would do it with a normal foreach.

Comment: The problem is `easyConfigService.ExecuteUnfinishedEasyConfigs();` is an `async` method but your `DoWork` method never `await`s it, which messes-up everything.

Comment: **Exactly** what do you mean by "Time Hosted Service"? What actual types/libraries/interfaces are you using? Where/how is the `DoWork` method invoked?

Comment: You cannot use the same context in `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. `DbContext` is not thread safe.

Comment: @Dai See above, how the Suncar context is added.

Comment: The TimeHosted service I use from the `services.AddHostedService()`

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Firstly, what is a `TimeHostedService`? I'm also struggling to understand what object are created and when. You should really try to give us a [mre].

Comment: @RafaelEberle `AddHostedService` uses `IHostedService` which has `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` methods - that doesn't relate to your `void DoWork` method - so (again), please show us **exactly** how `void DoWork` is being used.

Comment: @Dai I added the Exemple above, how I used the DoWork Method inside the StartAsync

Comment: @RafaelEberle You shouldn't be using `Timer` in this case - all you need is a `while` loop with `await Task.Delay`.

Comment: Probably I us the DoWork Method Wrong with a Timer?

Comment: Post the full exception, ie the output of `Exception.ToString()`. This will show where the error occurred and the stack trace that led to it. There are various problems with this code, eg the very fact `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is used with a *single* context is a huge bug that will cause crashes, but not an ObjectDisposedException. Unless some error handler disposes the invalid DbContext.

Comment: A DbContext is a Unit of Work, not a database connection so using `Paraller.ForEachAsync` with a *single* UoW makes very little sense. A UoW tracks changes to the objects it loads. That means you're modifying *the same objects* from multiple threads, then randomly saving changes in the middle of the modifications. If lucky, you'll get concurrency or thread exceptions. If you're unlucky and didn't enable optimistic concurrency, you'll get bad data. But not an ObjectDisposedException

Comment: @Dai Your Comment solved the Problem, now  everything is async up to the `StartAsync` from the TimedHostedService. Thank you <3

Comment: @RafaelEberle You should consider my posted answer below instead of my comment-replies.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We removed the Parallel.ForEachAsync and have to find now a better thread safe solution to speed up the code.

Comment: Speed up what? What's slow to begin with? I repeat, a DbContext isn't a database connection. If you want to perform multiple "transactions" you need to use multiple instances. That means creating instances *inside* `TryExecuteEasyConfig`. **BUT** ORMs in general are *not* meant for ETL jobs, and executing inefficient SQL 10 times can make things 100 times worse due to blocking. Fixing the perf problems can lead to 100 better performance. An `UPDATE ... SELECT` that never loads anything to the client usually is 100s f times faster than using an ORM to do the same work for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this document fully first: https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#asynchronous-programming

---

The problem is in your `DoWork` method: which you've defined as a normal `void` method when it needs to be an `async Task` method so that you can `await` the `TryExecuteEasyConfig` method.

...instead, what happens is the `DoWork` method itself will return as soon as the first `await` is encountered inside/via `easyConfigService.ExecuteUnfinishedEasyConfigs();`.

You haven't shown-us your `TimeHosted` service - nor really told us much about it, but I assume you're using `IHostedService` (which supports `async` methods as-is) with a non-`async`-safe Timer callback, such as `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`?

In any event, you don't need to use any `Timer` types, just change your code to this:

```cs
public sealed class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<SuncarContext> dbFactory;

    private readonly Object lockObj = new Object();
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task? loopTask;

    public MyHostedService( IDbContextFactory<SuncarContext> dbFactory )
    {
        this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }

    public Task StartAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        lock( this.lockObj )
        {
            if( this.loopTask != null ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Already running..." );

            this.loopTask = Task.Run( this.RunLoopAsync );
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        // TODO: add better reentrancy protection

        Task? rundownLoopTask; // <-- Make a local copy of `this.loopTask` for thread-safety reasons.
        lock( this.lockObj )
        {
            rundownLoopTask = this.loopTask;
        }

        this.cts.Cancel();

        try
        {
            await rundownLoopTask;
        }
        catch( OperationCanceledException ) // <-- This is an expected-exception.
        {
            // NOOP
        }
        finally
        {
            lock( this.lockObj )
            {
                this.lockObj = null;
                this.cts.Dispose();
                this.cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            }
        }
    }
    
    private async Task RunLoopAsync()
    {
        while( true )
        {
            await Task.Delay( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 60 ) );

            try
            {
                await this.RunLoopBodyOnceAsync( this.cts.Token );
            }
            catch( OperationCanceledException ) when ( this.cts.IsCancellationRequested )
            {
                throw; // Always rethrow this so the StopAsync method can observe it.
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                // TODO: Log the exception and decide if the loop should be aborted or not.
            }
        }
        
    }

    private async Task RunLoopBodyOnceAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        using( SuncarContext db = this.dbFactory.Create() )
        {
            IQueryable<Gateway> q = db.Gateways
                .Include( g => g.Machine )
                .ThenInclude( m => m.MachineType )
                .Where( g => g.EasyConfigStatus == EasyConfigStatus.OnGoing );
                
            List<Gateway> gateways = await q.ToListAsync( cancellationToken );

            DoStuffWithGateways( gateways );

            await db.SaveChangesAsync( cancellationToken );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will read through the document. I have also posted now the whole timeHosted service as it was when i started the Post.